# Windows 11 File Explorer keep getting refreshed by on its own suddenly

Tags: filesystems, windows-11

In my windows 11(up to date) laptop File explorer suddenly gets focused and refreshed. This happens suddenly. For example, I left file explorer open in one workspace and started working in another workspace. Then suddenly I get switched back to the workspace with file explorer open and I see that the file explorer is refreshing by on its own. Its becoming really irritating. I am using Mcafee Internet Security (Licensed).
What is the reason of this problem?

Comment: I am not seeing this on my own Windows 11 Pro daily driver machine for a year now.  I wonder if it might be a Mcafee issue running alongside Windows Defender. Are you able to disable Mcafee for a couple of hours and see if the File Explorer issue stays or goes away.

Comment: Try running DISM / SFC to see also if that helps.   .....    (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: @John I got `Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.` from the last command. Was I supposed to get any violations?

Comment: If no Windows error then the issue would appear to be related to Mcafee (appears to me).

Answer (score 0):

For me, it turned out to be triggered by my Desktop Background Slideshow.  I turned off the slideshow (Settings > Personalization > Background) and the behavior vanished.

As a happy side effect, my CPU usage also went from ~20% down to 4%.